# Why are the env variables for the Datastore Emulator incorrectly detected?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I run the Datastore emulator, and I get the following apparently correct console log

```
> gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project=myproj --data-dir "./gcloud_datastore"

[datastore] If you are using a library that supports the DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:
[datastore]
[datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8232
[datastore]
[datastore] Dev App Server is now running.
```

In another cmd window, while the emulator is running, I run the following, or alternatively  I stop the emulator first. Either way, it produces a different port and a different project:

```
> gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init

set DATASTORE_DATASET=anotherproj
set DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8297
set DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8297/datastore
set DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8297
set DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=anotherproj
```

What is going wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same data directory when running the `env-init` command. For example:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init --data-dir=./gcloud_datastore
```

When you start the Emulator using the `start` command, it creates/updates a file `env.yaml` in the specified data directory. This file contains the environment info (such as port, project name), which I believe is used by the `env-init` command.